# Excel VBA - How to calculate login/logout hours with different dates?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to figure out how to calculate log hours with different dates. 
Here's my sample code. It works fine but when the dates are different, it produces negative result.

```
 '03-14-2018   4:00:00 PM
 '03-015-2018  1:00:00 AM

 Login = 4:00:00 PM 
 Logout = 1:00:00 AM

 total = Logout - Login
 totalHours = (total / 1) * 24
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change it to `Login = #3/14/2018 4:00:00 PM#` and `Logout = #3/15/2018 1:00:00 AM#`

Comment: You can use The Datediff function : `totalHours = DateDiff("h", #3/14/2018 4:00:00 PM#, #3/15/2018 1:00:00 AM#)
    MsgBox totalHours`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using literal Date/Time then you can use it as

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim Login As Date, Logout As Date

    Login = #3/14/2018 4:00:00 PM#
    Logout = #3/15/2018 1:00:00 AM#

    Total = Logout - Login
    totalHours = (Total / 1) * 24

    Debug.Print totalHours
End Sub
```

If your time is in a `String` variable then you can use `DateDiff`

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim Login As String, Logout As String

    Login = "03-14-2018 4:00:00 PM"
    Logout = "03-15-2018 1:00:00 AM"

    Total = DateDiff("n", Logout, Login) / 60

    Debug.Print Total
End Sub
```